# How to sync Room Database with Google drive and work with multiple android devices in the same account?

Tags: android, android-room, google-drive-android-api

I'm not yet familiar with Room and Google Drive API and I would like to know if it's possible to create a Room database and store it in the hidden Google Drive App folder for sync across devices. If anyone implemented something similar, a short example would be great. Thanks!

What about using LiveData to observe when something changes in the Room database and then trigger sync to Google Drive?

Comment: I have experienced that files in the app folder are deleted when logging in from different devices but from the same account. I think that what you want to do is not desired by google.